# Atrtribute Value in XMLNode from XMLNodeList based on another Attribute Value

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XmlNodeList with 3 XmlElement.

I am trying to pull an attribute value from the nodes InnerXML based on a different attribute value...

An example of one of the XmlElement InnerXML is this:

```
<p:nvPicPr xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"><p:cNvPr id="5" name="Content Placeholder 4" title="https://myserver/image1.jpg" /><p:cNvPicPr><a:picLocks noGrp="1" noChangeAspect="1" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" /></p:cNvPicPr><p:nvPr><p:ph idx="1" /></p:nvPr></p:nvPicPr><p:blipFill xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"><a:blip r:embed="rId2" cstate="print" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"><a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0" /></a:ext></a:extLst></a:blip><a:stretch xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"><a:fillRect /></a:stretch></p:blipFill><p:spPr xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"><a:xfrm xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"><a:off x="7972166" y="1690688" /><a:ext cx="3830596" cy="2154710" /></a:xfrm></p:spPr>
```

So, in the abve node I would like to be able test if the value "rId2" is in the innerXml and if it is return the value https://myserver/image1.jpg

What is the way to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

Don't work with InnerXml - it's a simple string. Work with node list and attribute collection.

```
XmlNodeList list = ... // your list with 3 nodes

XmlNodeList descendants = list[0].ParentNode.SelectNodes("//*");

bool imageFound = false;
bool idFound = false;

foreach (XmlNode node in descendants)
{
    foreach (XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
    {
        if (attr.Value == "https://myserver/image1.jpg")
            imageFound = true;
        if (attr.Value == "rId2")
            idFound = true;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(imageFound);
Console.WriteLine(idFound);
```

Comment: Many thanks for helping - but this doesn't quite do what I need and I can't work out how to make it do it.... In 1 of the 3 nodes there will be a value = rId2 - from that node I am then trying to retrieve the value of "title"... Would you be able to help a little further?

Comment: @TrevorDaniel Attribute with value `rId2` is at the second node. The `title` attribute is at the first node. It is right? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: There are 3 nodes. Each have an attribute called "r:embed" and title. I am trying to work out how to search the 3 nodes and return the "title" when I know the "r:embed" value.

Answer (score 0):

Finally cracked it...

```
string oldRelID = part.GetIdOfPart(imagePart);

                    foreach (XmlElement list in pictureNodeList)
                    {
                        XmlNodeList elementList = list.GetElementsByTagName("a:blip");

                        foreach (XmlNode node in elementList)
                        {
                            foreach (XmlAttribute att in node.Attributes)
                            {
                                if (att.Value == oldRelID)
                                {
                                    XmlNodeList trevList = list.GetElementsByTagName("p:cNvPr");

                                    foreach (XmlNode trevnode in trevList)
                                    {
                                        foreach (XmlAttribute trevatt in trevnode.Attributes)
                                        {
                                            if (trevatt.Name == "descr")
                                            {
                                                mapReference = trevatt.Value;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```